# Appending to vector with non-dynamically allocated stack

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a coding question, and to solve it I'm creating my own data structure (class), "SetOfStacks", that has as a member a vector of stacks. In one of the member functions of SetOfStacks, I need to expand the vector using the push_back() function. To do this, I declare a stack variable (non-dynamically) in the member function and then pass that variable in to push_back().
The code works fine, but I don't understand why. I would figure that after the member function has finished executing, the stack variable would go out of scope (because it is not dynamically allocated) and as a result the vector would contain garbage. I would think that the solution would be to use dynamically allocated memory. Why does this work? My best hypothesis is that push_back() takes in the new stack by value and not by reference, effectively making a new copy of it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `push_back()` makes a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `push_back()` the stack elements to the vector, the element is passed by value to the vector, and not as a reference, so even if after the function definition the stack elements got destroyed, the vector has got the value already.

This you can related with the return value from function to caller. Even if the return value is local to function stack( i.e it is going to be destroyed after function gets executed), the return values gets copied to caller function before it gets destroyed.